# Can't convert data with Pandas from 'object' to 'float' in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some problems with data conversion in pandas. The data I use is from a .csv file, and the data is like this shaped:

```
In[1]: df1.head(5)
Out[1]: 
                 Min                Avg                Max
0   -23863,708361909  -48934,4147351092  -74207,2942236209
1  -13713,0154545259  -35353,7123879251  -54097,3098488292
2  -13713,0154545259  -34380,9550139847  -54460,3415715344
3   -13576,928997833  -29763,4415556726  -64341,8134999719
4   -13576,928997833   -28261,296700531  -54086,0282965991
```

For my case, I need to plot the column named 'Min' and for that I need to convert the string to float.
But, however, I can't convert the data to a float type data, so it's raising an error all the time.

The error message:

```
invalid literal for float(): -2888,46956828262
```

Tried with `convert_numeric`, `to_numeric`, `float(value)` and so on, but I can't get it to work.

What is the correct sintax for dtype conversion? How to convert the string data to float data correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is `-2888,46956828262` supposed to be? Is the comma a separator between the integer and fraction parts of a single number? Is it decorative, like 1,234,567,890 but somehow got in the wrong place? Is it separating two different numbers (like -2888 and 46956828262)?

Comment: It's a single float number.

Answer (score 1):

You have comma "," inside your number that's why it is not converting it to float.

```
value = "-2888,46956828262"
value= value.replace(",",".")
x = float(value)
print x
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it!

Comment: Made an edit it should work.

Comment: That's a long way of writing `value = value.replace(',', '')`. It seems unlikely that there would be only one comma in a random place inside the number and that it'd have no meaning.

Comment: thank you, I modified the code. yes but the error is because of the comma. I was not sure of the context of data.The question is edited later.

Answer (score 1):

Works in python2 and python3

```
s = "-2888,46956828262"
f = float(s.replace(',','.'))
print (f)
```

Comment: Easy and clean! thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the numbers you expect are formatted in a locale that uses a comma as the decimals separator. To parse such a number, determine the locale first (for instance, in France, that would be "fr_FR") and set it accordingly.

```
from locale import delocalize, setlocale, format, LC_NUMERIC
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'fr_FR.UTF-8')

parse_this = '-2888,46956828262'
```

---

```
>>> print(delocalize(parse_this))
'-2888.46956828262'

>>> my_float = float(delocalize(parse_this))
>>> print(my_float)
-2888.46956828262

# Then, if you need to print this number elsewhere:
>>> print(format('%f', my_float))
-2888,4695682826

# You might also need to adjust padding
>>> print(format('%16f', my_float))
    -2888,469568
```

External input must always be validated; this includes determining correct locale of data. If you need to parse CSV, you have to make the system locale-compliant, and determine the locale of the data you wish to parse.

If you want your code to remain portable across different locales, avoid methods using string substitution and regular expressions, as they tend to be brittle and require lots of coaxing to suit different locale combinations:

- different conventions for money,
- spaces around groups of decimals,
- commas,
- dots,
- negative and positive signs
- negatives signified with parentheses around the number expression,
- and various other oddities.

### Issues with CSV

CSV stands for Comma-separated values. As it says, values are separated with commas, so people came up with other means of encoding numbers in CSV files:

```
MyNumber,OtherColumn
"-412,932459",The other column
"-401,999999",And another one
```

Although this allows encoding the locale of the original system inside the file, a parser that does not expect things to be inside double quotes might interpret this value as a literal string instead of potentially a number expression, and obviously, a parser that is not aware of locales will probably fail to parse this expression as a decimal number, at all.

Comment: Nice! I hoped there would be a more localization-related solution.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Cheers :-)